# Batch script to copy file from windows to linux server

Tags: windows, batch-file

Can someone suggest me how to write a Batch file to copy from windows to linux even the size of file is 0 and file name having a unique pattern and unique extension.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/- " %%x in ("%date%") do set d=%%z%%y%%x
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:. " %%x in ("%time%") do set t=%%x%%y%%z
set logfile="D:\\FTP%d%_%t%.log"
set Source="\\srcpath"
set Server="servername"
set UserName="id"
set Password="pwd"
set File="ABC.TXT.yyyyMMdd"

set FtpLocation="/home/TEST"
perl Getfile.pl %Source% %server% %UserName% %Password% %FtpLocation% %File%  >> %logfile% 2>&1
```

getting issue with perl in connection with server.So expecting to use only Batch file or only Perl file.

Comment: if ftp is available, the use it, else look at using WinSCP.

Comment: Batch file:-
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=/- " %%x in ("%date%") do set d=%%z%%y%%x
for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:. " %%x in ("%time%") do set t=%%x%%y%%z
set logfile="D:\xyz\Logs\srcFTP_%d%_%t%.log"
set Source="\\srcpath"
set Server="servername"
set UserName="id"
set Password="pwd"
set File="ABC.TXT.yyyyMMdd"

set FtpLocation="/home/abc/"
perl Getfile.pl %Source% %server% %UserName% %Password% %FtpLocation% %File%  >> %logfile% 2>&1`

Geting error in perl while connection.

Any other easy way to do?

Comment: I am looking to do with batch file only ,no external tool will be in used.

Comment: yet, you are using perl, which is external. please post the `Getfile.pl` code.